# For Loop OLS regression(Matlab)

Tags: matlab

I have a `50x1000` matrix with a randomly generated data from an AR(1) process. It is basically 1000 samples with 50 observations each. I have to estimate the coefficient of each sample of 50, 1000 times. I have to regress each column on its 1 period lag. I was not sure how to set up the for loop to do this, with the lagged value. Can anyone suggest a way for me to do it? This is what I have so far.

```
rho=0.9;

u = randn(1000,1000);
y = zeros(1000,1000);
for i=2:1000
  y(i) = rho*y(i-1) + u(i);
  for j=1:1000
      y(i,j)=rho*y(i-1,j)+u(i,j);
end;
end;

m=y(951:1000,1:1000);
```

This code generates my data and the `m` matrix is the last 50 observations of the Monte Carlo process that I have to estimate rho for. So `m` here is a `51x1000` and I have to do OLS for each column regressing that column on its 1 period lag. I would appreciate help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not quite familiar with how you are "regressing" here, but I have a few comments.  1.  You said you have a 50 x 1000 matrix, yet your matrix is 1000 x 1000.  Comments?  2.  You can make this completely vectorized and escape any `for` loops.  We can tackle that after I ask the next question.  3.  Your `y(i)` statement is indexing a single dimension.  In this case, because MATLAB is column major, it will only operate on the first column.  Is this intentional?

Comment: Hi Rayryeng. I was referring to the m matrix, which I create from the y matrix. That one is 50x1000. For the Y(i), basically, my first loop generates a single column 1000x1 series of data. The second loop does that 1000 times as I have to generate 1000 samples. Let me know if something is still not clear. I`d really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: To further clarify, from that m matrix which is 50x1000, i have to regress each column on its 1 period lag. So, my first column has some 50x1 data and I need to regress that on that data lagged 1 period. I have to do that for all 1000 columns.

Comment: OK, you realize that your `y(i)` statement will generate the *same* data for the first column at each iteration, yes? Is that intentional?

Comment: Given the way it is setup, my first row(or in other words the first observation for each sample will be 0). Hence, my first row in the 1000x1000 matrix is a 0. Yes, that is intentional. However, I am not sure if that is what you were referring to. Other than that, the code generates different random samples(in each columns) except the first observation in each column which is 0. I hope I answered your question. Btw, you can easily run the code as it is, if something is still unclear.

Comment: Rayryeng if I still haven't answered your questions I apologize, but I am not particularly experienced in Matlab. I would appreciate it if you can adjust my code the way you think it should be, and given that maybe suggest how I can do the regression i am trying to figure out. Thanks.

Comment: That's no problem.  Give me a few minutes to parse through what you said. I'm still having difficulty understanding what you want to do

Comment: Basically, I have this m matrix(ignore the code that I have posted above), which is 50x1000. That is, it has 1000 samples of 50 observations each. Now, what I have to do is that I have to estimate the coefficient with OLS for each of the 1000 columns. It is like treating separately each column and I have 1000 different data sets with 50 observations for which I have to get the OLS coefficient. If I take the first data set(column 1) as an example I have to regress this data(the 50 observations in column 1) on the 1 period lagged value of that same data.

Comment: So my y variable is the data in column 1(which has 50 observations) and my x variable is the same data,but lagged for 1 period.And I have to do this for each column, so 1000 times.

Comment: I wrote this for loop which clearly doesn't work, but it might be helpful to explain what i am trying to do.

Comment: for i=1:50
    for j=1:1000
    series1=regress(m,k);
    series1(i,j)=regress(m,k);
end;
end;

Comment: m is my m matrix and k is the same matrix but lagged one period. I was trying to loop through each column taking into consideration all 50 observation of each column, but this clearly is not properly set up.